# symbian learning

Tags: symbian

I am very new to this Symbian C++. I want to learn the symbianc++ very clearly and keenly.Could you please refer the book for me? Which is the efficient book for learning Symbian C++.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are plenty of titles. The best is "[Symbian C++ Explained](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470021306)" from Jo Stichbury. It is not the newest one, but all information here are still valid. It was announced that there will be a 2nd edition, but it was never published...

Then there are two titles of similar quality (you should have at least one of those) [Developing Software for Symbian OS 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470725702) and [Symbian OS C++ for Mobile Phones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470066415).

As a quick reference guide is good the title [The Accredited Symbian Developer Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470058277)

I have read all those books and they are all really good.

As you might notice starting approx. from Symbian^1 (but Qt is available from also on for older OS versions) there is also growing support for Qt and since Symbian^4 the Qt will be the only way how to create UI, so it might be good to start looking also on some Qt book. There is one related to Symbian mobile development called [Qt on Symbian](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470750103).

I think it is enough reading for at least year:))

BR
STeN

Answer (score 0):

If you really interested in learning the *original* Symbian C++ (and perhaps most common Symbian OS APIs), then I totally agree with comment from STeN. However, the original Symbian C++ was all about supporting "leaving" functions (due the lack of C++ exceptions) and "two-phased" object construction (actually just for the same reasons). The rest was just about some basic Symbian OS APIs and Symbian OS consepts (like desciptors, Symbian application structure and active-object mechanism). Also knowing the basics of Symbian in-house C++ utility library called "User" was required to make some useful programs for Symbian OS.

Last years the Symbian OS developers has made a lot for suppporting the modern C++ with exceptions and STL (with some other useful libraries) on the last versions of Symbian OS. Also the plain C was made available for developers on Symbian OS. That's all was done for easier porting of applications outside of the Symbian C++ world. The Qt framework was one of such successfully ported examples.

Anyway, Nokia has a good snapshot from the book "The accredited Symbian developer primer" made available online: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Fundamentals_of_Symbian_C%2B%2B

It's really good to get started with the Symbian C++ and some of the most important Symbian OS APIs.